# Angular view is not refreshed in a correct way on Submit

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have a Angular page with different views in the same html page. When I use this one that delete the selected name from the `selectoption` and press the submit the deleted name is still in the `selectoption`.

```
<div class="container">
  <div [hidden]="submitted">
    <h1>Delete Person:</h1>
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #deletePersonForm="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="personInd">Name</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="personInd"
            required
            [(ngModel)]="personInd.id" name="personInd"
            #id="ngModel">
          <option *ngFor="let ur of person" [value]="ur.id">{{ur.name}} 
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div [hidden]="!submitted">
    <h3>Person deleted</h3>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" (click)="onSubmit()"> 
      Delete another Person
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

the ts-calls:

```
onSubmit() {
  if(this.submitted==false) {
    this.httpServiceService.deletePersonById(this.personInd.id,this.person);
    this.submitted = true;
  }
  else {
    this.submitted = false;
  }
}
```

And a service:

```
deletePersonById(id:number,personArr:Person[])
{
this.http.delete('//localhost:8080/deletePerson'+"/"+id)
  .subscribe( data => {
    personArr = personArr.filter(u => u !== personArr[id]);
  });
```

}

But the service work fine and the data is correct. If I update the page it will be correct updated and the deleted names will not be there.

Is there a way to refresh when submitting a button. I have read a lot of different posts and some suggests `location.reload()` but that reloads the whole page and not the selected view or the div.

Any suggestion?

Comment: please share your .ts file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your deletion is working correctly. The problem your view is not up-to-date after the deletion results in the way you update the `personArr`.

You're passing the reference to your local person array as parameter to your `deletePersonById`. In this method you're removing the deleted person from the array using the build-in filter function. But this function returns a new array and does not update the existing one, so the change is not reflected in component's array. You have to return the new array to your component or need to update the array there after the successful deletion.

I would suggest removing the deleted person in your component with:

```
onSubmit() {
    ...
    // After successful deletion
    this.person = this.person.filter(person => person.id !== this.personInd.id);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once your delete is successfully performed, you'll also have to manually delete it from your local `person` array.

Try this:

```
onSubmit() {
  // After you delete the person
  const personToDelete = this.person.filter(person => person.id === personInd.id)[0];
  this.person.slice(this.person.indexOf(personToDelete), 1);
}
```

Comment: You're using person in your Template and `personArr` in your Component Class. Why is there an inconsistency?

Comment: Just a mistake. Will correct that, have tried so many things so there is some issues in the code.

Comment: Sorry for not responding, forgot laptop at work, I will try to make sure that person is deleted correct and see if it works then